# Can you explain this method of finding prime numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, primes

```
function getPrimes(max) {
var sieve = [], i, j, primes = [];
for (i = 2; i <= max; ++i) {
    if (!sieve[i]) {
        // i has not been marked -- it is prime
        primes.push(i);
        for (j = i << 1; j <= max; j += i) {
            sieve[j] = true;
        }
    }
}
return primes;
}
```

I understant that `i` keeps track of all numbers.

i don't understand...`!sieve[i]`,`j = i << 1;` & what is really happening.

Just to be Clear.. Prime Number is something that is only divisible by itself or by one.

Comment: The [`<<` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#<<_(Left_shift)) is a bitwise left shift. Shifting by `1` is going to multiply by `2`, so `j = i * 2` would do the same thing.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Ugh, the "right shift instead of multiplying by two" thing. Premature optimization at its worst. (And utterly pointless since any compiler/interpreter worth its salt will do that automatically anyway.)

Comment: i didn't write this so yea lol

Comment: There is another potential bug lurking here when discussing the difference between multiplying by two and using a bitwise left shift.  The bitwise left shift operator produces a signed 32 bit result (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.7.1). Where as multiplication by default produces double-precision (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5.1)

Comment: And `j = i * i` would be much faster, because the loop would have a lot less to do (unless there is another Javascript WTF lurking there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

From Wikipedia ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes )

> A prime number is a natural number which has exactly two distinct
>   natural number divisors: 1 and itself.
>
> To find all the prime numbers less than or equal to a given integer n
>   by Eratosthenes' method:
>
> - Create a list of consecutive integers from 2 to n: (2, 3, 4, ..., n).
> - Initially, let p equal 2, the first prime number.
> - Starting from p, count up in increments of p and mark each of these numbers greater than p itself in the list. These will be multiples of
>     p: 2p, 3p, 4p, etc.; note that some of them may have already been
>     marked.
> - Find the first number greater than p in the list that is not marked. If there was no such number, stop. Otherwise, let p now equal
>     this number (which is the next prime), and repeat from step 3.
>
> When the algorithm terminates, all the numbers in the list that are
>   not marked are prime. The main idea here is that every value for p is
>   prime, because we have already marked all the multiples of the numbers
>   less than p.

Comment: I understood it after watching this video :D

Answer (score 5):

It's called the [Sieve of Erathestenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and it's an efficient way of finding all prime numbers between zero and some upper limit integer.

```
j = i << 1
```

This is a bit shift operation. It shifts an integer 1 bit to the left. Because binary is base two, this is equivalent to multiplying by two. In decimal, the equivalent operation would be shifting, say, `1` to the left and bringing in a zero to the right. It's base ten, so you end up with `10` (ten times one.)

I don't believe the implementation you show is optimal. The limit to the `i` value can be lower -- something like `sqrt(max)`.

You can easily find some really nice animations online of this algorithm that show you what's going on in quite an intuitive way.

Comment: "don't believe ... optimal": The inner loop never runs after i is greater than the square root of max, so after that point the outer loop is merely collecting primes, not computing additional primes. If you limit i to be less than the square root of max you will need another loop at the same level as the current outer loop to collect the remaining primes, so the function as written works fine. An optimization is to sieve only on odd numbers, not even numbers.